# Swift Array extension with generic function parameter

Tags: swift, generics

I am using Swift 4 and looking for a way to create extension function for array collection with arguments of type

```
typealias Listener<T> = (T) -> Void
```

however extension below cannot be created (Use of undeclared type 'T')

```
extension Sequence where Element == Listener<T>{
    func callAll(t: T){
        self.forEach { $0(t) }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627256/6541007) can be some hint for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot introduce new generic parameters at the header of an extension like `T` in your code, but each method can have generic parameters.

```
typealias Listener<T> = (T) -> Void

extension Sequence {
    func callAll<T>(t: T)
        where Element == Listener<T>
    {
        self.forEach { $0(t) }
    }
}
let listeners: [Listener<Int>] = [
    { print($0) },
    { print($0 * 2) },
]

listeners.callAll(t: 2)
```

Comment: simple solution so I mark it as an answer, thank you